# Skip password in user login

Tags: loopbackjs

I have written my own login function to a service which verifies username/password and I wish to still use LoopBacks user-model. The problem is to get an accesstoken (and keep a User logged in within the LB-application) I need to provide a password. Storing the password in Loopbacks datasource is not an option. My question, how do I tell Loopback the user is actually verified and can be logged in without password? From what I can see in the User.Login code there is not an option to skip password and just login the user.

This is all done programatically, I'm using a custom user model which has the user model as base. Below is a simplified example:

```
CustomUser.beforeRemote('login', function(ctx, unused, next) {
    UserService.externalLogin(ctx.args.credentials.username ,ctx.args.credentials.password).then(function(response){
      //Go to user.login
      if(response.authorized){
        next();
      }
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best practice, but I would actually add a custom login entry point for the `custom-user.js`:

```
CustomUser.customLogin = function (email, cb) {
        var tokenTimeToLive = 12096000; //in ms
        CustomUser.findOne({
            where: {email: email}
        }, function (err, user) {
            if (err) {
                return cb(err, null);
            } else {
                if (user) {
                    user.createAccessToken(tokenTimeToLive, function (error, token) {
                        return cb(error, token);
                    });
                } else {
                    return cb(new Error("No User found"), null);
                }
            }
        });
    };

    CustomUser.remoteMethod('customLogin', {
        accepts: {arg: 'email', type: 'string', required: true},
        returns: {arg: 'credentials', type: 'object', root: true},
        description: "Custom login entry"
    });
```

And a custom ACL for this method in your `custom-user.json`:

```
...
"acls": [
    {
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone",
      "permission": "DENY"
    },
    {
      "accessType": "READ",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$authenticated",
      "permission": "ALLOW"
    },
    {
      "accessType": "WRITE",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$authenticated",
      "permission": "ALLOW"
    },
    {
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone",
      "permission": "ALLOW",
      "property": "customLogin"
    }
  ]
...
```

Of course you might want to use another field than the `email` one but I think it's also a primary key on the Loopback `User` model.
But you will always need to post a programatically generated password for the Users when you Post a new one.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, F3L1X79, I was hoping to get around the generate-token part. What I ended up with is a hybrid of this and still using the login-function where I generate the token if the user is authorized. :)